# In the SC II Editor, how is the High Templar's weapon assigned?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

Having trouble understanding how entities in the Editor are linked together.

In particular, I noticed the High Templar unit has no entries in its Weapons array. Yet it obviously has its Psi Blast weapon.

I found a reference to `HighTemplarWeapon` in `BalanceMulti.SC2Mod`'s XML, but it doesn't show up in the editor's "table view". Is this what's giving the High Templar its weapon? Does the default (table) view just not show all of the data?

Comment: The map I'm using to explore this data *does* have a dependency on VoidMulti.SC2Mod, but for some reason the Swarm.SC2Mod version of the unit was showing up. After quitting and re-opening the map, the High Templar is showing its Psi Blast weapon. Weird.